# How did Lord Vishnu complete the curse of 100 years of separation from Mahaa Lakshmi?

Tags: krishna, radha, curse

I heard a story about Lord Vishnu getting a curse of 100 years of separation from Mahaa Lakshmi. One Mahaa Rishi did put this curse on Vishnu when his wife was being killed by Vishnu. He said in his curse that "like I am suffering from separation from my wife, in the same way you will also suffer from separation with Mahaa Lakshmi.

To complete this curse Lord Vishnu has to suffer from separation of 100 years. As per my knowledge, Lord Vishnu did complete this curse in his eighth incarnation. He took incarnation as Krishna and Mahaa Lakshmi took incarnation as Radhaa.

Both spent their childhood together but they had to separate from each other because of the curse. So one day they got separate.

Now, the confusing part for me here is, Krishna lived on earth for nearly 125 years. He had to separate for 100 years. Out of remaining 25 years, He spent some years with Radhaa And later got married to Rukmini.

But I heard that Radhaa and Rukmani are the same. [In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMz5B0PmF8c) it is explained in brief how both of them are the same.

Now the question is, if Krishna actually married Radhaa herself who was later known as Rukmini, then how did he complete the 100 years of separation since he lived only 125 years?

I mean, out of the remaining 25 years, how many years Krishna did spend with Radhaa in his childhood and for how many years Krishna was the husband of Rukmini/Radhaa? It is not like that He married Rukmini (Radhaa) after he was 100 years old and spent the married life for few years only. Did they get rid of the curse by any way?

Comment: Radha and Rukmini being the same person is a folk story not given in any of the scriptures.

Comment: @dr.vineetaggarwal Yes, I got aware of this later. But still I wonder how/when Lord Krishna separate for 100 years with Mata Rukmani since his life span was only around 125 years.

Comment: Krishna was still a teenager when he left for Mathura right. And then he met Radha ji at the solar eclipse fair towards the end so possible that they met after that long a time.

Comment: @dr.vineetaggarwal Ohh yes, Because I was thinking Rukmani and Radha as same person, So I was comparing saperation time of Krishna and Rukmani instead of Krishna and Raadha. May be 100 years saperation curse Raadha got, not Lord Vishnu. The curse I mentioned in question is different one which Vishnu fullfill but not as Krishna. Am I right?

Comment: Yes possibly the curse was only for Radha ji who BTW arrived on Bhu Loka 14 years before Krishna.

Comment: @dr.vineetaggarwal Great, You can post this info as an answer. You can describe in detail both are different person and curse info I provided wrong in question. Rishi gave curse but not of 100 years. The curse of 100 years was given by different rishi and to Raadha, not to Vishnu/Lakshami.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Brahmavaivarta Purana: Prakrti-Khandam: Chapter 49. Pronouncing of curse mutually by Radha and Sudama](https://archive.org/details/BrahmavaivartaPuranaWithEnglishTranslationVolume1/page/n477):

> 46 In the sacred forest of Vrndavana in the land of Bharata, Krsna the lord of the cowherds enjoyed the company of Radha in Vrndavana for a short duration.
>
> 47 Thereafter because of the curse 
>   of Sudama both of them were separated from 
>   each other.
>
> 48 **After the lapse of a hundred years**, both Krsna 
>   and Radha met each other while on a pilgrimage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Actually when I asked this question then I thought Radha and Rukmani (Incarnaion of Lakshmi) are same. But later I got to know that Radha is not incarnation of Lakshmi. And curse was given to Raadha, not to Rukmani (Lakshmi).

Comment: Curse given by lower stratum like rishi to god wont be applicable until unless they themselves accept them.. Radha Rani is not an incarnation of Lakshmi. The love of Vrindavan gopis is different from human love. Human love will always have some portion of physical relationship, I belive Krishna left when 12 years. Not as adult or adolescent.. so this is pure love.